# Android Studio debugger works only once

Tags: android, android-studio, breakpoints, android-debug

I have Android Studio version 3.6.1, and Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41. Breakpoints added in my application, works only once when I delete and reinstall app. If app was closed and then open, breakpoints aren't active, and application don't stops on it. Option "attach debbuger to android process" also doesn't work. Have anyone idea which may cause this problem and how to fix it?